# Multiprocessing: unexpected KeyBoardInterrupt happens in one process

Tags: python, multiprocessing, keyboardinterrupt

I've been running a long-lasting multiprocess-script doing some calculations. But suddenly one of the processes stopped due to `KeyBoardInterrupt` exception. In other words, it is not me who pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> or something similar, it's just an individual process who got this exception. The rest continued to work. That's how it looked in console output:

```
20000000 equations processed so far by process #14
15000000 equations processed so far by process #9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Projects\test_project\src\test.py", line 55, in <module>
    main(key)
  File "D:\Projects\test_project\src\test.py", line 25, in main
    enumerator.start(operand_variations, progress_callback, 1000000)
  File "D:\Projects\test_project\src\equation_enumerator.py", line 53, in start
    queue.put(node)
  File "C:\Users\Amega\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 89, in put
    if not self._sem.acquire(block, timeout):
KeyboardInterrupt
18000000 equations processed so far by process #1
18000000 equations processed so far by process #15
```

If that matters, the processes were spawned in simple way:

```
for i in range(self.processes):
    p = mp.Process(target=self.process_variants,
                   args=(i, queue, output_dir, progress_callback, progress_callback_every))
    processes.append(p)
    p.start()
```

They then poll a mp.Queue, holding the tasks. After which I simply `join()` them. The script is run under Windows. Even more specifically, I launch it from [PyCharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#IDEs) using "Run Configuration" (if that also matters).

What can be the reason for that? Is it possible that the process was interrupted by OS, or something else "external" (including maybe PyCharm itself)? My first suggestion is that something sent [SIGINT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#SIGINT) to that specific process, but I don't have any idea what it can be. Since these calculations take a lot of time and it's a bit problematic right now to handle pausing/resuming the whole process, I would like to know what can be the reasons so I could negate them. Or at least be just aware of them. I can, of course, place a "try/catch" inside the routines, but that will also disable an intended interruption.

It seems it's actually the main process which got interrupted (according to trace: `queue.put(node)` - tasks are generated by it). But it's still a somewhat "external" interruption, done not by me. Another idea I got is that it can probably be related to me being away from the keyboard, so computer was idle in terms of other activities (sleep is disabled in Windows).